# Why show me error to create new symfony project?

Tags: symfony

When I execute this command: `symfony new my_project`

- Creating a new Symfony project with Composer
  WARNING: Unable to find Composer, downloading one. It is recommended to install Composer yourself at https://getcomposer.org/download/
  (running C:\Users\pimubi.symfony5\composer\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton D:\wamp64\www\symfony\my_project  --no-interaction)

Creating a "symfony/skeleton" project at "./my_project"

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package symfony/skeleton with stability stable in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [] [] []

Show me that error:
`unable to run C:\Users\pimubi\.symfony5\composer\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton D:\wamp64\www\symfony\my_project  --no-interaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the requirements for Symfony and install the missing ones (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#technical-requirements)

In case you have installed Symfony CLI, you can check your requirements with this command:

```
symfony check:requirements
```

It seems like you are missing PHP and/or Composer.